# Why is Java picking this overload over the other

Tags: java, overload-resolution

Could anyone explain to me why Java is picking the second overload instead of the first?

```
public static void foo (int a, double b, double...c) {}
public static void foo (double...a) {}
public static void bar ()
{
    // this is the second
    foo(1);
}
```

I thought when I pass `1` as the argument, Java would have picked the first argument because `int` is more specific than `double`?

Thanks

Comment: Ok if `1` was passed to `int`, what would go into the `double` type which is 2nd argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second method is the only one that can match.  You have only 1 argument.  The first `foo` has at least two required: an `int` and a `double`, so that can't match.

The second `foo` matches because any number of numbers can match.  Java will implicitly promote your `int` `1` to a `double` so it can match, with method invocation conversion.